# partial specialization of nested type in std

Tags: c++11

Consider simplified linked list implementation in C++11

```
template<typename T>
struct list
{
    struct node
    {
        T value;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<node> root;
};
```

Now, if I have linked list, which cleans itself in its destructor using `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor. The destruction could be recursive if compiler is not clever enough in optimalizations. If we had trillions elements in our list, it could be an issue (stack overflow).

So, to help the compiler I would not use `std::default_delete` for `std::unique_ptr`, but rather bring my own implementation

```
template<typename T>
struct my_list_delete
{
    void operator()(T* ptr) const
    {
        std::stack<T*> nodes;
        // use explicit stack instead of call stack in recursion
    }
};
```

And all nodes would be `std::unique_ptr<node, my_list_delete<node>>`. It is nice, but I have to write more code for every `std::unique_ptr` I have. Instead, I could partially specialize std::default_delete!

```
namespace std
{
template<typename T>
struct default_delete<typename list<T>::node>
{
    void operator()(typename list<T>* node) const
    {
    }
};
}
```

But this does not work. As long as I know the type used to instantiate list, I can plug that in. But if I want to make it generic, I am stuck at

> error C2764: '`T`': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization '`std::default_delete<list<T>::node>`'

I there a way to get around this in C++11? I was thinking about using SFINAE

```
namespace std
{
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if</*T is list*/>::type>
struct default_delete<T>
{
    void operator()(T* node) const
    {
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be to write a using declaration for that type:

```
using node_ptr = std::unique_ptr<node, my_list_delete<node>>;
```

Comment: That would work, but I am more interesed in `std::default_delete` solution

Answer (score 1):

You can "unnest" the inner class:

```
template <typename T> struct list_node {
    T value;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

template<typename T> struct list {
    using node = list_node<T>;
    std::unique_ptr<node> root;
};

namespace std {
    template<typename T> struct default_delete<list_node<T>> {
        void operator()(typename list<T>* node) const { }
    };
}

default_delete<list<T>::node>()(...); // works
```